# EC2 AWS 405 (Not Allowed) and CORS problems with NGINX FrontEnd && BackEND

Tags: nginx, post, amazon-ec2, axios

I have a front-end app with reactjs and back-end with express where locally i send the front-end data by using `localhost:3333` with axios, got no problem with that.

Now i'm trying to use an EC2 AWS instance to host this application but got no success.

The ec2 instance is only for tests, so it public DNS IPV4 is: `http://ec2-18-228-222-138.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/` and public IPV4 is: `18.228.222.138`

When i try to POST method into server acessing the public DNS, i get a message from console browser saying:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://18.228.222.138/uploadFile' from origin 'http://ec2-18-228-222-138.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

When i try to POST by public IPV4 (18.228.222.138) i get from console browser: `405 (Not Allowed)`.

I can't figure out what i'm missing where.

**My codes and configs:**

Running back-end on port **3333** with `npm start` or `pm2 start npm -- run server`. 
`Index.js` code:

```
import cors from 'cors'
import express from 'express'
import routes from './routes'
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload'
import shell from 'shelljs';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express()

app.use( cors({ origin: '*' }) ); //enable any origin here
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(fileUpload({
  useTempFiles : true,
  tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
}));

app.use(routes);
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.listen(3333);
```

Block 'scripts' in back-end package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec sucrase-node ./src/index.js",
    "server": "babel-node ./src/index.js",
},
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name http://ec2-18-228-222-138.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com ;

    location / {
        root /var/www/FullFinalPaper/front-tcc/build;
        try_files $uri /index.html;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location /var/ww/FullFinalPaper/front-tcc/src/services/api.js {
        proxy_method POST;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://18.228.222.138/3333;
   }
}
```

Axios config, front-end to back-end:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://18.228.222.138',
});

export default api;
```

EC2 instance with all outbound ports enable and inbound all SSH, HTTP and HTTPS enable.

Comment: Can you share the full set of request and response headers?

Comment: I think i didn't undestand your question. Did you mean the information on the network tab of the browser console?

Comment: if so, i uploaded the images of full set request here: https://imgur.com/a/YE3zQVC. The first image is about the 405 not allowed problem and the second cors problem. Was this you asked or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution.

In second location path into nginx config it must indicate the URL path for POST method, in my case `/uploadFile`.

In the end, my Nginx config was like this:

```
upstream backend {
        server 18.228.223.186:3333;
        server 18.228.223.186;
        server localhost:3333;
}

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name 18.228.223.186;
        root /var/www/FullFinalPaper/front-tcc/build;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/tcc.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/tcc.com.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        rewrite //index.html last;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location /uploadFile  {
        proxy_method POST;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        error_page 405 =200 $uri;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That 405 makes it seem more like an issue with POST not being allowed by your web server.